# how to render a template in vuejs

Tags: jquery, html, vue.js

I am using jQuery and vuejs of version 2.3.4:

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js`

I have the following code:

```js
      // initialize the vue.
      vueVar = new Vue({
        el: '#content',
        methods: {
          // Start by creating a function to inject a menu link to the dom.
          inject_menu_link: function (menu_title, menu_url, menu_type) {
            if($(menu_type + ' li').length){
              // if the menu exists
              template = '<menuLinkTpl v-bind:url="'+menu_url+'" v-bind:name="'+menu_title+'"></menuLinkTpl>';
              $(menu_type + ' > li').last().after(template);
            }
          },
        },
        components: {
          // make a menu template to add; given the url and the title of the menu
          'menuLinkTpl': {
            props: [{
              // menu link url
              url: '',
              // menu link name
              name: '',
            }],
            template: '<li><a v-bind:href="\'/\'+ url " v-bind:title="name">{{name}}</a></li>',
          },
        },
      });
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <ul id="block-menu">
      <li><a>menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a>menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

**What i want to acheive** is to be able to add a new menu item to the menu
**whenever** i *call the function* `vueVar.inject_menu_link('menu link title', 'url-test', '#block-menu')`

now **what is happening** is that:

`<menuLinkTpl v-bind:menuurl="/url-test" v-bind:menuname="menu link title"></menuLinkTpl>`

this is what being appended to the dom **without** it being rendered.

how can i fix this?

Comment: This is a jQuery-like approach, it's not how it is supposed to be done with any MVC/MVVM framework/library such as Vue.js. Stop thinking in DOM elements, start thinking in lists that your Vue iterates over and updates, when you add or delete an item in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a `v-for` for that

```
export default {
    data () {
         return  {
             menuItems: [{ .. initial value ...} ]
         }
    },
    methods: {
        injectMenu () {
            menuItems.push({}).
        }
    }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <ul id="block-menu">
      <li is="menuLinkTpl" v-for="menu in menuItems" :url="menu. ..." :name="menu. ..."></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Dynaimcally adding content should not be done using text with vue. This is because vue need to create a virtual DOM for better performance. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html If you read carefully the doc you can use the `createElement` and mimic your text injection.